# Google MAps API V2 Error inflating class fragment

Tags: class, fragment, google-maps-api-2

I have searched a lot for the solution of this. But nothing was useful. I feel like this problem has no solution. Thought of giving it a last try by uploading my problem.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidmapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBD9fsiMd_G9Pzeq2Eqas2FwJjzMGbSOnA" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Log Errors**

```
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidmapsv2/com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at com.example.androidmapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    ... 11 more
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    ... 21 more
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
04-08 14:35:19.799: E/AndroidRuntime(27534):    ... 24 more
```

**google-play-services_lib** has also been added to the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a FrameLayout (id: map_container) and call this :

```
private void displayMap() {
    Log.d(TAG, "displayMap");
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_container).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_container, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            initMap(googleMap);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Reply. But it appears that i am still having some problems.
if i extend MainActivity with Activity I am getting the following error
**The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity**
And if i extend MainActivity with FragmentActivity The App crashes with the following Logcat error.
**04-08 18:57:37.449: E/AndroidRuntime(32191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cus/com.example.cus.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.cus.MainActivity**

Comment: Your activity need to extends ActionBarActivity from android.support.v7.app. Try with this and tell if it works.

Comment: No I am still getting the error
**04-08 23:18:06.661: E/AndroidRuntime(3365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cus/com.example.cus.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.cus.MainActivity**
I have Updated my SDK, tested Using other phone but no +ve result. I just need the map to be displayed in my Application... :'(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this!! :D
I downgraded the **ATD** (from 23.0.6 to 22.3.0 ) and **SDK** , and it worked perfectly...
Maybe it was some compatibility issue..

Comment: Downgraded is not a solution. There is something wrong somewhere else but I can't see where at this moment.